# React custom hook: can't get an async function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I've got a button that calls an async function, that is returned by a call to a custom React hook, alongside with a reactive prop that I need to keep track of.

[CodeSandbox here](https://codesandbox.io/s/quizzical-cloud-grq1y?file=/src/App.js).

```js
// useEmail.js
import { useState } from "react";

export default function useEmail(message) {
  const [returnedMessage, setReturnedMessage] = useState("old");

  const send = async () => {
    // fake fetch
    const whatever = await fetch(
      "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1"
    );
    setReturnedMessage("new");
  };

  return {
    returnedMessage,
    send
  };
}
```

And this is the app

```js
// app.js
import React from "react";
import useEmail from "./useEmail";

export default function App() {
  const { returnedMessage, send } = useEmail();
  const run = async () => {
    console.log("returnMessage PRE", returnedMessage);
    await send();
    console.log("returnMessage POST", returnedMessage);
  };
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h2>Click and wait for 1 second</h2>
      <button onClick={run}>Click me</button>
      <h2>Returned message:</h2>
      <p>{returnedMessage}</p>
      <button onClick={() => window.location.reload()}>
        Reload to test again
      </button>
      <p>
        It prints "new", but logs "old"
        <br />
        even if I await send()...?
      </p>
    </div>
  );
}
```

`useEmail` returns both a `returnMessage` string, that is initialized as `"old"`, and an async function `send` that fetches something, then flips the `returnMessage` and sets it to `"new"`.

How is it possible that in the `<p>{returnedMessage}</p>` the value correctly turns from `"old"` to `"new"`, while the Console logs always `"old"`, even if I `await` when calling `send()`?

[image]

It seems like `send()` is not really treated as an asynchronous function – I've tried in different ways but I always have a correctly updated rendering but a wrong value when I need it in the function for further processing.

Thank you for your help

Comment: Does this answer your question? [useState set method not reflecting change immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54069253/usestate-set-method-not-reflecting-change-immediately)

Comment: Sounds promising: "Also, the main issue here is not just the asynchronous nature but the fact that state values are used by functions based on their current closures, and state updates will reflect in the next re-render by which the existing closures are not affected, but new ones are created. Now in the current state, the values within hooks are obtained by existing closures, and when a re-render happens, the closures are updated based on whether the function is recreated again or not." Not sure if I can  implement that in my real project (contact form in a Gatsby w/ Netlify serverless funcs)

Answer (score 1):

You can do the job using `useRef`.

It seems you can't access the updated value without running the hook again.
With `useRef` you'll get a reference and you can access the data at any time, without running the hook again.

```js
// useEmail.js

export default function useEmail(message) {
  const messageRef = React.useRef("old");

  const send = async () => {
    // fake fetch
    const whatever = await fetch(
      "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1"
    );

    messageRef.current = "new";
  };

  return {
    messageRef,
    send
  };
}
```

```js
// app.js

export default function App() {
  const { messageRef, send } = useEmail();
  const run = async () => {
    console.log("returnMessage PRE", messageRef.current);
    await send();
    console.log("returnMessage POST", messageRef.current);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h2>Click and wait for 1 second</h2>
      <button onClick={run}>Click me</button>
      <h2>Returned message:</h2>
      <p>{returnedMessage}</p>
      <button onClick={() => window.location.reload()}>
        Reload to test again
      </button>
      <p>
        It prints "new", but logs "old"
        <br />
        even if I await send()...?
      </p>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image]

Comment: useRef works in that example (it didn't occur to me to use it in this context, thanks for mentioning it) but fails in my actual code because I've got to switch another value (besides "message", I've "isLoading") a couple of times. It starts as false, then is set true, then false again: `useRef` is not able to pick these intermediate changes, alas.

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 async functions in your custom hook.

- Your fetch (which one you await)
- `setState`

So even if you await for the fetch, your setState is still asynchronous:

- `console.log("returnMessage PRE", returnedMessage); //old`
- Fetch
- Await fetch to complete
- Fetch complete
- trigger setState
- function `send()` returns `undefined` (because no return is defined)
- `console.log("returnMessage POST", returnedMessage); //old`
- State is updated (async setState is complete)
- `returnedMessage` is updated
- Component re-renders

If you want to have actions depending on when `returnedMessage` is changed, you'll have to use `useEffect` in your component

```js
useEffect(() => {
    if (returnedMessage === "old") return; // Do nothing here
    // returnedMessage !== "old" so assume it's "new"
    // Do something...
}, [returnedMessage]);
```

Answer (score 0):

It is a normal behaviour setState will produce only a single re-render at the end of the event even if you used await, try to add a console.log inside your component you will see  returnedMessage moved to 'new'

```
// app.js
import React from "react";
import useEmail from "./useEmail";

export default function App() {
  const { returnedMessage, send } = useEmail();
  console.log("returnMessage POST", returnedMessage); // in last render it will be new so it will change the view
  const run = async () => {
    console.log("returnMessage PRE", returnedMessage);
    await send();
  };
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h2>Click and wait for 1 second</h2>
      <button onClick={run}>Click me</button>
      <h2>Returned message:</h2>
      <p>{returnedMessage}</p>
      <button onClick={() => window.location.reload()}>
        Reload to test again
      </button>
      <p>
        It prints "new", but logs "old"
        <br />
        even if I await send()...?
      </p>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Yes! But I think he wants to use the value of `returnedMessage` right after the `send` function is resolved. And this is the problem

Comment: It will be the same ('old') since the re-render will not fire until the end of the function run

Answer (score 0):

One thing that I noted, from your custom React Hook, you are returning an `async` function.
which is this:

```
async () => {
    // fake fetch
    const whatever = await fetch(
      "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1"
    );
    setReturnedMessage("new");
  };
```

And within your App Component, you are accessing the custom hook where `send` is pointing to this `async` function. Right?

Now when you are calling your async function you are trying to do:

```
await send();
```

Why `await` here again, since we already have an `await` inside of our function.

When you do this you are basically waiting for a `promise()` here, since every `async` function returns a promise even when nothing is returned.

I feel the implementation of custom hook should change or calling the hook has to be different.

On top of this `setState()` is itself an asynchronous action. That is not in our control to tell when the state will update :)

Comment: Searching I've found some vaguely-related questions, and answers were implying the use of Promise.all() but I haven't been able to successfully implement it. I initially had the doubt that destructuring `{ returnedMessage, send }` isn't explicit enough in setting `send` as an async function – for even if the function body awaits for fetch, it kinda behaves like a sync one. Unless I really need to resolve the promise somehow

Comment: Our main issue is happening only because of asynchronous nature of **setState()** call. In hooks  **setReturnedMessage("new");** this call :) I also felt like serial promise handling stuff should be there. But this thing  setReturnedMessage("new"); is asynchronous but await does work on it. I mean **await setReturnedMessage("new");** has no effect at all... In Classes setState(), we used to pass second argument to person a task when state is sure to be updated. But now it's the world of HOOKS